# OpenStreetMap display as simple as Google Maps

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm glad OpenStreetMap exists at all, but I find their display has way too much details.

Here's an example of the same location:

[image]

Is there a way to view OSM contents with the same level of details as Google Maps, especially on smartphones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a look at the tiles provided by MapQuest Open. They are free to use (attribution required), based on OpenStreetMap but with different rendering. Check [this wiki article](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MapQuest#MapQuest-hosted_map_tiles) for more info, or you can just take a look at the MapQuest basemap by going to [openstreetmap.org](http://openstreetmap.org), clicking the Layers button on the right hand side of the map and choosing MapQuest Open. You can use MapQuest open tiles the same way you use OSM tiles e.g. http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/8/126/87.png

If you're feeling adventurous you can also look at [generating your own tiles](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Creating_your_own_tiles). I'm afraid this is way beyond anything I've ever wanted to tackle, but there is a big community who regularly do things like this and I'm sure you'll find plenty of support and help on here as well.

Alternativey I believe [CloudMade](http://cloudmade.com/products/map-tiles) offer paid services to generate custom tiles. The ones I've seen are pretty damn beautiful as well, so it might be worth a look.

Comment: MapQuest has more generalised data in some cases (roads), Cloudmade would be the best solution here without creating custom raster tiles.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I was just looking at ready-to-use solutions since I neither have the skills nor the time to write my own layer. Looks like MapQuest Open is the closest equivalent to Google Maps.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of maps using openstreetmap data. You can find an overview here:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/List_of_OSM_based_Services

A very reduced map is designed by stamen:

http://maps.stamen.com/watercolor/#12/37.7706/-122.3782